# Поиск числа состоящего из 1 и 2, делящегося на 2^n (Time limit exceeded)

Tags: python, python-3.x

В [Школе программиста](https://acmp.ru) решал довольно интересную задачку. Надо найти число, которое делится на 2^n, при этом состоит только из цифр 1 и 2. Вот так я составил свое решение:

```
n = int(input())
num = 2**n
while num:
  s = set(str(num))
  if s == {'1', '2'}:
    break
  else:
    num += 2**n
print(num)
```

но оно не проходит по времени (1 сек). Посоветуйте где исправить код чтобы сократить время. Спасибо!

Comment: Нужно найти любое такое число, или минимальное?

Comment: И как минимум, проверка `num % 2**n == 0` в Вашем коде лишняя, поскольку у Вас по определению все перебираемые `num` делятся на `2**n`.

Comment: Конкретики в условии нет. Искомое число состоит не более чем из 10 000 цифр и n не превышает 300. Согласен, что лишнее, сразу не пришло в голову)) и если не минимальное, то проверку чисел состоящих только из 1 или 2 тоже можно убрать

Comment: Ну и добравшись до num > 3*10^k, можно сразу прыгать на 1*10^(k+1) - это сократит количество тестов чуть ли не впятеро...

Comment: напиши номер задачи потестировать

Comment: 453. Раз-два, раз-два

Comment: Принимая во внимание условия входных данных (n до 300, итоговое число до 10 000 (**десяти тысяч**) цифр), ясно, что решать эту задачу надо не перебором.

Comment: А как называется задача в Школе Программиста?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
def check(number):
    while number > 0:
        if (0 < number % 10 < 3):
            number //= 10
        else:
            return False
    return True


n = 7

template = 2 ** n
number = template

while True:
    if (check(number)):
        print(number)
        break
    number += template

# 122112
```

Comment: n = 12 и засеките время.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно понимать, что последняя цифра искомого числа не может быть единицей, т.к нечетное число не делится на 2^n(за исключением случая n=0, но тогда любое число из двоек и единиц подойдет). Также важно понимать, что если число делится на 2^n, то либо оно делится на 2^(n+1), либо на какое-нибудь другое простое число, отличное от 2. Причем во втором случае надо учитывать, чтобы умножение не вышло из "поля" единиц и двоек. Вот пример такого выхода:

```
xxxxx2 * 2,3,5,7...P = xxx4(вышло), xxx6(вышло) xxx10(вышло), xxx14(вышло)
xxxxx4 * 2,3,5,7...P = xxx8(вышло), xxx12(НЕ ВЫШЛО), xxx20(вышло), xx28(вышло) 
xxxxx6 * 2,3,5,7...P = xxx12(не вышло), xx18(вышло), 30(вышло), xx42(вышло)
xxxxx8 * 2,3,5,7...P = xxx16(вышло), x24(вышло), xx40(вышло), xx56(вышло)
```

Несмотря на то, что простое число может быть большим, тем не менее можно было бы попытаться составить таблицу первых 5-10 простых чисел и среди них найти все комбинации умножения, не выходящие из множества единиц и двоек.

Может быть конкретно данный набор тестов можно было бы пройти, используя метод грубой силы - комбинаторику: найти все размещения 2 и 1 в числах длины 1,2,3..N - пока среди вычисленных размещений на i-ом этапе (i < N) не окажется число, делящееся на указанную степень двойки.